# Converting timestamp object in json to timestamp as a string

Tags: json, mongodb, awk, jq, datetime-format

I have a json exported from Mongodb . It shows timestamp in a different format
`"timestamp":{"$date":"2020-08-01T00:00:00Z"}}` . I want to convert this timestamp object to a string like `"timestamp":"2020-08-01T00:00:00Z"` .

I have done this using sed like `s/\{\"[$]date\":\"(\S{20})\"}/"\1"/g;`. However , the length of the timestamp may vary if milliseconds are added to the time .Eg : `"timestamp":{"$date":"2020-08-01T00:00:00.123Z"}}` would be transformed with  `s/\{\"[$]date\":\"(\S{23})\"}/"\1"/g;` , since the length of timestamp string is 23 characters. I want to convert this into a single transformation step where any length for the string would be good.

I can do this with jq too but that will need to read every line , store the value in a variable and use awk to change the value . This would be time consuming as compared to sed . So looking for a different solution.

A good answer would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use `jq` for parsing/modifying JSON data.

Comment: jq doesn't do inplace editing

Comment: `jq ... INPUT | sponge INPUT`

Comment: What's wrong with plain old `jq ... INPUT > tmp && mv tmp INPUT`?

Comment: @EdMorton -- Concurrency?  (Especially if you mean "tmp" literally.)

Comment: @peak by `tmp` I mean a temp file. What issue did you have in mind for "inplace" editing vs using a tmp file when you said "concurrency" - execution speed or multiple entities writing to the same file simultaneously or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton - “multiple entities writing to the same file simultaneously”, of course, though that’s obviously less concerning if e,g. mktemp is used.

Comment: @EdMorton i dont disagree that can be used , and concurrency can be handled by using variable as a filename

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got it worked out . This answer is for those who are looking for a similar solution .

`cat test.json | jq ' .location.timestamp = .location.timestamp."$date"' | sponge test.json`

I didn't know how to use sponge, sponge is great!

Comment: FYI: there's another unix tool for json manipulation - `jtc` - it's as power as jq. `jtc` is capable of in-place file modifications (so you can do it in one command w/o piping to sponge). E.g., you query in `jtc` (with in-place file modification) would look like this: `jtc -x'<timestamp>l:' -y[0] -y[0][-1] -sf test.json`. PS. I'm a developer of the `jtc`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
walk( if type == "object" and has("$date")
      then .["$date"] else . end )
```

This risks losing data, so you might want to consider similar alternatives, e.g. a stronger precondition, or a precondition using the expected key name. Or you might want to raise an error if the "date" object is not as expected.

Comment: walk is a linux tool , can u elaborate  like how to use the filename in the command etc ..

Comment: more importantly how will this edit the file , it same as using jq as i have written in the question

Comment: My answer gives a jq solution.  The `walk` in my answer is a jq function.